# Factor out a matrix if it's being multiplied by a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm pretty sure we can do the following, but I just want to confirm.

A$\vec x_1$ + A$\vec x_2$ + A$\vec x_3$ + A$\vec x_4$ = A( $\vec x_1$+ $\vec x_2$+ $\vec x_3$+ $\vec x_4$)

Comment: Yes we can. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the (column) vectors $\vec x_i$ are $1 \times n$ matrices, suppose first that $A$ is an $n \times 1$ matrix, i.e. a row vector, say $\{a^i\}$

so in this case (using a sum of two vectors to start with, and using the subscript to indicate the scalar components, rather than different vectors)
$$
A\vec y = \sum_i a^iy_i
$$
a scalar. you can see that
$$
A(\vec y + \vec z) = \sum_i a^i (y_i+z_i) = \sum_i a^i y_i+\sum_i a^i z_i = A\vec y + A\vec z
$$
if this is true for one row, it is obviously true however many rows $A$ has. now show that this  *linearity* easily extends to a matrix multiplying a sum of more than two vectors.